# The sum of $1+1+1+1+...$

Tags: summation, puzzle, infinity

My teacher recently showed me a rather weird result and I would like to know if he was just tricking me or if he was serious. 
He showed me that $g=1-1+1-1+1-...=\frac{1}{2}$
Then he said that $s=1+1+1+1+1+1+...=\frac{1}{2}$ as well because when you add $g$ and $s$, the "ones" in the even columns cancel out and the "ones" in the odd columns add up to $2$'s, so you end up with $2+2+2+2+2+...$ you can factor out a two and get the equation: $s+g=2s$
If $g=\frac{1}{2}$, then $s+\frac{1}{2}=2s$ tells us that $s=\frac{1}{2}$ as well.

Where did he trick me?

Comment: Yes. He tricked you.

Comment: Sometimes teachers are wrong.

Comment: if $x=1+1+1+1+1+1\dots$ then $x=x+1$. So right off the bat we know $1+1+1+1+1\dots$ can't be a number if we want numbers to make sense.

Comment: Could you explain how he showed you 1-1+1-1+1... = 1/2? I'm just curious what the argument could have been.

Comment: There is a variant definition of convergence in which $1+(-1)+1+(-1)\cdots$ converges to $1/2$. It's called "Cesaro summability." But there isn't a good definition of convergence where $1+1+1+\cdots$ converges.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCu_BNNI5x4 and more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function .. so, i dont think he "tricked" you..

Comment: @Francisco: whenever someone uses infinite objects as if they are finite, and without previous justification, they are tricking you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that kind of stuff always make think when i am "working" with series or sequences.. the Riemann’s Rearrangement Theorem for me is very strange too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yeap ! but is wrong? I do not know. I think a lot of people argue with calculus without even thinking the context.. like complex numbers..

Comment: @Francisco It's wrong, unless you are specific about the context, which that video is not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok, I'm not arguing about the video, I think i expressed myself wrong about that.. But i put the link to wikipedia too. where has things like 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... = - 1/12. and the context where that its possible.

Comment: Technically, there is no "context where that is possible." You can say that $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$, you can't say what you wrote. You can't say $1+2+2^2+2^3\cdot = \frac{-1}{5}$, which is even "more" true. (This is actually true in a context, but without the context, it is false.) @Francisco

Comment: Basically, it is all deeply lazy notation to make you go "wow!" about something that isn't true. That's practically the opposite of good mathematics. @Francisco

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see. now I understand where I made the mess to express myself .. Thanks. To prevent pollution in chat, you can delete my unnecessary comments..

Comment: There is a reasonable sense in which $1+1+1+1+....=-1/2$ (that is, $\zeta(0)=-1/2$).  So it looks like your teacher got the sign wrong.

Comment: Does your teacher happen to be a physicist by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up "divergent series" for example on wikipedia if you want to see various "sensible" ways to add up divergent series and get a finite answer, e.g. that are compatible with algebraic manipulations. However any possible way that you get a finite answer for a divergent series is just a "trick," and there is no one right answer, because the series doesn't converge in the traditional sense.