# What can we say about the series: $-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What can we say about this series? $$-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$$

Intuitively, the sum of it seems to converge to zero, as each term cancels the one before it, although none of the convergence tests seem to work on the series. Also I have no idea as for how to calculate the limit     $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n$, which would have enabled me to at least some degree to determine what is going to happen with this sum.

Comment: The sequence $(-1)^n$ doesn't converge, so you can't find a limit for it.

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: Bakk as a simple explanation, everytime you increase by one term, sum keeps hopping, once its $0$ then it is $-1$. So always sum keeps doing this, should you call this behaviour as convergence?

Comment: @Bak1139: For the corresponding series to converge, the sequence has to converge to $0$ in the first place. You may want to look up the definition of a convergent sequence on wikipedia.

Comment: it's a basic exercise to show the divergence of $(-1)^n$ you can probably google it

Comment: This has been asked a 1000 times on this site. A simple search will give you the answer...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum of $1+1+1+1+...$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134139/the-sum-of-1111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n$ doesn't exist, then, in particular, it is not $0$, and therefore the series diverges.

Comment: how did you know it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Bak1139 Because it doesn't approach a single value? It oscillates. Just as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin x$ does not exist...

Comment: @Bak1139 Because the limit of the subsequence $1,1,1,\ldots$ is $1$, whereas the limit of the subsequence $-1,-1,-1,\ldots$ is $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, using the standard definition of convergence, we can say about this series that it does not converge. This is easily seen when looking directly at the partial sums:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^1 (-1)^n &= -1\\
\sum_{n=1}^2 (-1)^n &= 0\\
\sum_{n=1}^3 (-1)^n &= -1\\
\sum_{n=1}^4 (-1)^n &= 0\\
&\ldots
\end{align}$$
Obviously that sequence never remains close to any value.

Now for any non-standard definition of convergence (and there are many of them), as long as they fulfill a few reasonable conditions, you can say:

**If** the series converges according to some criterion, its value has to be $-\frac12$:

We have
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n &= -1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\\
&= -1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\\
&= -1 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n
\end{align}$$
and therefore
$$2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n = -1.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the series to convergence the sequence within would have to be convergent to zero. Since it's not the series does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

It's divergent, and it oscillates between two numbers, you cannot find a limit of such a series.

Comment: There is a great video by Mathologer about this and other infinite series that explains how you can and cannot manipulate the limits, to get the answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuIIjLr6vUA&t=1988s

Answer (score 1):

As you and the other answerers know, this series does has no sum when you use the standard first definition of convergence as the limit (if it exists) of the partial sums.

There are fancier ways to think about summing series. You can start reading here:

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Summation_methods\

and here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of not convergent infinite series we can assign values by [Cesàro sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), defined as the limit as $n\to \infty$ of the sequence of arithmetic means of the first $n$ partial sums of the series.

In this sense we can assign to the series (aka [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series)) the value $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

It is divergent so it does not have a value ,but one can obtain it to be $-\frac12$.
Correct me if i'm wrong below

Proof:

Consider : $S =-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+...........$

Now ,add brackets :

$S = (-1+1)-(-1+1)-(-1+1)-.......=0$

One can change the order of the brackets without changing the value:

$S = -1 +(1-1)+(1-1) +(1-1).......= -1$

add the two, giving $2S = -1 \implies S =-\frac12$

A closely related series is the [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) which is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i$ which evaluates out to $\frac12$

Comment: With that calculation, you could get any value for $S$. For example, add three times the first and four times the second “equality” to obtain $7S=-3$, thus $S=-3/7$. Or subtract twice the first from the second to obtain $-S=-1$, that is $S=1$. Indeed, the two equations $S=0$ and $S=1$ *contradict* each other, therefore you can derive literally anything from them (like $0=1$, just subtract the second equation from the first).

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at the definition of a limit. We say that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a$$

IF for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have:
$$|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$$

This is not the case for $0$, $1$ or $-1$.